# Pointers to objects in a set or in a vector - does it matter?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, set

just came a across a situation where I needs to store heap-allocated pointers (to a class B) in an STL container. The class that owns the privately held container (class A) also creates the instances of B. Class A will be able to return a const pointers to B instances for clients of A.

Now, does it matter if these pointer are stored in a set or a vector? I thought of having a set just to verify that no duplicates are stored but since addresses are stored, two B pointers with the same data can be stored (unless I provide a comparison class for data comparison I presume).

Any thoughts on this (quite vague) subject? What are the pros/cons for the alternatives? Are smart_pointers something to look into?

Please ask me if anything imperative is unclear, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with storing pointers in a standard container - be it a vector, set, map, or whatever. You just have to be aware of who owns that memory and make sure that it's released appropriately. When choosing a container, choose the container that makes the most sense for your needs. vector is great for random access and appending but not so great for inserting elsewhere in the container. list deals with insertions extremely well, but it doesn't have random access. Sets ensure that there are no duplicates in the container and it's sorted (though the sorting isn't very useful if the set holds pointers and you don't give a comparator function) whereas a map is a set of key-value pairs, so sorting and access is done by key. Etc. Etc. Every container has its pros and cons and which is best for a particular situation depends entirely on that situation.

As for pointers, again, having pointers in containers is fine. The issue that you need to worry about is who owns the memory and therefore must worry about freeing it. If there is a clear object that owns what a particular pointer points to, then it should probably be that object which frees it. If it's essentially the container which owns the memory, then you need to make sure that you delete all of the pointers in the container before the container is destroyed.

If you are concerned with there being multiple pointers to the same data floating around or there is no clear owner for a particular chunk of memory, then smart pointers are a good solution. Boost's `shared_ptr` would probably be a good one to use, and `shared_ptr` will be part of C++0x. Many would suggest that you should always use shared pointers, but there is some overhead involved and whether it's best for your particular application will depend entirely on your application.

Ultimately, you need to be aware of the strengths and weaknesses of the various container types and determine what the best container is for whatever you're doing. The same goes for how to deal with pointer management. You need to write your program in a way that it's clear who owns a particular chunk of memory and make sure that that owner frees it when appropriate. Shared pointers are just one solution for that (albeit an excellent one). What the best solution is depends on the particulars of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Why would there be any duplicates in the first place? If class A is the sole entity responsible for *creating* the instances, and it holds the container privately, meaning there's no way for others to mutate it, it seems to me that there should be no cause for duplicates. Well, if there is, won't that be remediable by some checking prior to adding the pointer to the vector?

I don't know why it would matter if you store a pointer in what kind of container. Containers don't really manipulate their data, they only provide access to them in different ways. So, it's up to you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store pointers in stl containers, use shared_ptr.

Now, the set sounds completely wrong. What are you going to do with those?
If you need to add and remove, then list.
If you need to iterate over range, or all, then vector.
If you need to access specific, knowing a key, then map.
Take a look at others as well. One size doesn't fit all.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is that any decisions that you make have be be with your goal in mind. If you need a 'no duplicates allowed' rule that a set enforces, then use a set. If not then you might want to use a vector or any container might do the trick.

As for smart_pointers yes, they are really really useful. Should they be used? I don't know, once again I don't know what your end goal is or the problem that you are trying to solve with them.

Basically it comes down this. If I said "I want to use a hammer. What do you think of that?" you would probably say "Well what for, I know that hammers are pretty good for nails and wood scenarios but they could also be used as a tool to hurt people or maybe as a book stand. Look, just wait a second, what is this for again?" The problem is that I have not, really said why I want to use a hammer. I have not said what goal I am trying to achieve.

So if you have sort of an overall goal then why not let us know, then it will be obvious if you are using the right tools for the job and we can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, stick with vector unless you have a real reason not to. Sets come with some runtime overhead as well as quite large semantic overhead compared to a vector.